# Enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a problem using an enum in Typescript.

```
export enum RegistrationStatusEnum {
        Pending,
        Rejected,
        Approved,
        InManagement,
    }
```

**UserDTO.ts**

```
import { RegistrationStatusEnum } from "../../Enums/RegistrationStatusEnum";

export class UserDTO {
  Name: string
  RegistrationStatus: RegistrationStatusEnum
}
```

**OtherTS.ts**

```
disableStatus(currentUser: UserDTO):boolean
    return currentUser.RegistrationStatus.Pending || currentUser.RegistrationStatus.Rejected || currentUser.RegistrationStatus.InManagement;
}
```

When I try to access Pending or other enum, I get an error **The 'Pending' property does not exist in the 'RegistrationStatusEnum' type** What is happening? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentUser.RegistrationStatus` is an enum value, it can be one of the enum members, but to check that you need to use `===` operator and compare with the specific field from the enum:

```
disableStatus(currentUser: UserDTO): boolean {
    return currentUser.RegistrationStatus === RegistrationStatusEnum.Pending 
        || currentUser.RegistrationStatus === RegistrationStatusEnum.Rejected 
        || currentUser.RegistrationStatus === RegistrationStatusEnum.InManagement;
}
```